# Adding rows dynamically to a table, where the layout was designed

Tags: android, dynamic, tablelayout

I was wondering if I can add rows of  data dynamically to a table whose layout was already defined...for ex :

```
<TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/myTableOrders"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/ordersRow"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.6"             
                />                                      

                <TextView android:id="@+id/quantity"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                />

                <TextView android:id="@+id/total_price"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                />
            </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Consider this table, where each row has those 3 textviews, with that styling...Can I give data to each of the textviews now ?...or should i also write the styling in the Java code that handles the population?

If yes..maybe you can give me a hint :)

EDIT : Solved this programatically using the code below

```
TableLayout ordersTable = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableOrders);
    for (int i=0;i<products.size();i++){

        //Create a new row to be added.
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //Create text views to be added to the row.
        TextView name = new TextView(this);
        name.setText(products.get(i).getName());
        name.setTextSize(16);
        name.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        TableRow.LayoutParams nameParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.6f);
        nameParams.setMargins(7, 5, 0, 0);

        TextView quantity = new TextView(this);
        quantity.setText(products.get(i).getQuantityString());
        quantity.setTextSize(16);
        quantity.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        TableRow.LayoutParams quantityParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams( TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.2f);
        quantityParams.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 0);

        TextView totalPrice = new TextView(this);
        totalPrice.setTextSize(16);
        totalPrice.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        TableRow.LayoutParams totalPriceParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams( TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.2f);
        totalPriceParams.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 0);

        tr.addView(name,nameParams);
        tr.addView(quantity,quantityParams);
        tr.addView(totalPrice,totalPriceParams);

        ordersTable.addView(tr);
```

Comment: What do you mean by giving data to textViews ? Do you mean setting text for each of them?

Comment: Yes...I mean i don't want to search and write java code for margins, weights, colors and so on...If it is possible

Comment: If you just want to set text for these already defined TextViews, in java code, you can just use `setText("text")`

Comment: and how is the connection made between that setText, and each textView?...

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, use something like

```
  TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name); //do this for all text views : retrieve them using Ids.
  tv.setText("someText") //someText = text that you want to set
```

Comment: That should be `R.id.name` not `R.id.@+id/name`

Comment: i'm afraid that didn't work...i think that the ids need to be unique?

Comment: yes, id has to be unique, you can check **`http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html`** OR  **`http://androidforums.com/application-development/177809-textview-settext.html`** for any more details